# windowShouldClose(_:) delegate function not being called in code

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am currently trying to learn Cocoa through a Mac Apps book and one of the programs has the windowShouldClose(_:) delegate function. However, when I run the program, the window will still close whenever this function is supposed to be called. The program still runs, but the window closes. Can anyone explain why this happens? Here is my code:

```
import Cocoa

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController, NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate, NSWindowDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var speakButton: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var stopButton: NSButton!

let speechSynth = NSSpeechSynthesizer()

var isStarted: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        updateButtons()
    }
    }

override var windowNibName: String {
    return "MainWindowController"
}

override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    updateButtons()
    speechSynth.delegate = self
}

//MARK: - Action methods

//get typed-in text as string
@IBAction func speakIt(sender: NSButton){
    let string = textField.stringValue
    if string.isEmpty {
        print("string from \(textField) is empty")
    } else{
        speechSynth.startSpeakingString(string)
        isStarted = true
        }

    }
@IBAction func stopIt(sender: NSButton){
    speechSynth.stopSpeaking()
}

func updateButtons(){
    if isStarted{
        speakButton.enabled = false
        stopButton.enabled = true
    } else {
        speakButton.enabled = true
        stopButton.enabled = false
    }
}

//Mark: NSSpeechSynthDelegate
func speechSynthesizer(sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer, didFinishSpeaking finishedSpeaking: Bool){
    isStarted = false
    print("finished speaking=\(finishedSpeaking)")
}

//Mark: Window Delegate
func windowShouldClose(sender: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return !isStarted
}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to set your main view controller as the delegate of the NSWindow.

In your windowDidLoad, you can set self as the delegate for the window

```
override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    updateButtons()
    speechSynth.delegate = self
    self.window.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What Shripada said is correct, but there's also another catch. Don't forget to make a connection from your `MainWindowController` to the window defined in your xib, otherwise the window outlet won't be referencing anything.

So, the window defined in your File's owner[image]

should reference the window in interface builder
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`windowShouldClose()` was not being called in my code either after upgrading to Swift 5. In previous versions, it was sufficient to have the app delegate inherit from NSApplicationDelegate for it to receive the `windowShouldClose()` notification (building in Xcode). Upgrading to Swift 5, I had to have my app delegate also inherit from `NSWindowDelegate` to get the notification. This declaration restored the window close notification to my app:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate {
```

Answer (score 0):

your method signature has to match exactly.
it has to be

windowShouldClose(_:)

the _ is important.